# How to specify a different audio player for use with Google Reader?

Tags: audio, google-reader, podcast

When I use the Google Reader app for audio podcasts -- e.g. linked MP3 files -- it pops up a simple player overlay to play the file (shown in screenshot). Is there a way for me to choose an installed audio player to use in place of the one used by the Google Reader app as the default player for the app?  Ideally I'd like the app to pop up an intent that asks me for the audio player to use, like many apps pass off responsibility for a well defined purpose.

[image]

The Google Reader app is [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.reader&hl=en).

Comment: Personally I've found that a dedicated podcatcher is a better option. I use Doggcatcher but there are quite a few out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Reader allows choice of external program (via intent) to play audio.

Comment: When did this happen? I don't see anything in the "What's new" section on Google Play, and the latest version of Google Reader appears to be from July, so nothing has happened since the question was asked.

Comment: Maybe it was specific to my phone. Removed the word "now" from the answer because it seems speculative under the circumstances. Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, I fired up Google reader and found a post with an embedded MP3 in it, and I was prompted which player I want to use to open it.